# Interactive ZoomGraph in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, zooming, interactive, shinyjs

Is it possible to create interactive Shiny graph that when you click zoom button on a Shiny Page, the graph will expand to the entire size of the browser window? Right now I have four ggplots on one shiny page and would like to expand one to full screen size when I click zoom. I think it could be using either shinyjs or conditional panels, but can't seem to figure it out. This has similar logic:https://gallery.shinyapps.io/105-plot-interaction-zoom/, instead of zooming in the graphic, would just like to zoom the entire graphic to the browser.

Thanks!

Comment: You could create a dynamically changing panel, then for "full-screen" mode define it as a fixed, absolute panel with something like `absolutePanel(fixed=TRUE,right=0,left=0,top=0,bottom=0,draggable=FALSE, wellPanel("the plot"))` . You could exit full-screen with a click event on an observe function.

Comment: Hey @Zediiiii thanks for the answer. I went down that pathway and found that it didn't work because it was sort of recursive in the sense that I had to create four UI, zoom to a specific UI, and then go back to all four UI. Just didn't work well in the server.R and ui.R file interactions. My solution was muchd easier actually and I ended up using [Shiny BS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyBS/shinyBS.pdf) that has a built in modal function.

Comment: Sweet - that's a nifty package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was much easier actually and I ended up using [Shiny BS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyBS/shinyBS.pdf) that has a built in modal function.